# Inverse matrix for $M_{kn}=\frac{i^{(k-n)}}{2^n}\sum_{j=0}^{n} (-1)^j \binom{n}{j}(n-2j)^k$

Tags: matrices, inverse

Good day,

I look for the inverse-matrix *formula* given the original matrix formula

$$M_{kn}=\frac{i^{(k-n)}}{2^n}\sum_{j=0}^{n} (-1)^j \binom{n}{j}(n-2j)^k,$$

where $M$ is a square matrix with $k,n \le N$. Because $M$ is lower triangular, $M^{-1}$ is also and its elements do not depend on $N$.

Thank you.

Comment: You just have to explore a bit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_number

Comment: @F.Jatpil : Do you mean $\det(M^{kn})$ ? Otherwise I don't understand your equation.

Comment: Find matrix $Q^{n,l}$ such that $\sum_n M^{k,n}Q^{n,l}=\delta^{k,l}$. I would like to find a formula for each element of $Q$ as function of $n$ and $l: Q^{n,l}=f(n,l)$. I was maybe wrong to use upper indices to indicate the element of the matrix. I corrected it.

Comment: @user90369: I believe $M^{kn}$ simply stands for the element in position $(k,n)$ in the $N\times N$ matrix $M$ and we are asked to find $M^{-1}$ in a explicit way. This is related to the Taylor series of $\cosh$ and $\frac{1}{\cosh}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio : Thanks for your hint! --- Such things should actually be explained by the OPs. :-)

Comment: @F.Jatpil : Use $\enspace\displaystyle \sum\limits_{j=0}^n (-1)^j {\binom {n}{j}} (n-2j)^k = 2^n n! \delta_{k,n}\enspace$ which means $\enspace M^{k,n} = i^{k-n} n! \delta_{k,n}\enspace$ and put this into your equation above to get $\,Q^{n,l}\,$ (and please choose one common or at least  understandable type of symbols) .

Comment: @ user90369 : you are obviously wrong: choose $k=3, n=1$. Sum has two terms: $j=0$ and $j=1$: $(-1)^0 \binom{1}{0}(1-0)^3+(-1)^1\binom{1}{1}(1-2)^3 = 1+1=2$. Matrix $M_{k,n}$ is not diagonal!

Comment: Yes, sorry, you are right. The formula works only for $k\leq n$ .